# "Shooting fail" error as response to "startMovieRec" request from Sony DSC QX10 camera?

Tags: python-3.x, sony-camera-api

I'm getting shooting fail error (code error: 40400) each time I try to start movie recording. I checked "getShootMode" returns movie and the "cameraStatus" is IDLE. What can cause this error?

All the other APIs works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I call the method "actTakePicture", the response returns the URL of postview image within result but I can't find any stored picture in the memory card (blank card as it was!). So I changed this card with another, then everything backs to normal.

I also realized that once I formatted the first memory card and copied some file in it (just to make sure the card wasn't write protected), it resolved my problem (no more errors from "startMovieRec") and I had pictures and videos stored.